# Split words from string in Prolog

Tags: list, split, prolog, dcg

I want to split words from string and put into a list in Prolog.

```
num --> [one] | [two] | [three] | [four] | [five].

?- split("onethreetwofive", Ls).
Ls = [one,three,two,five].             % expected answer
```

Here, I want to split the string with matching list from `num` and put the words in list. I am using SWI-Prolog. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Have you looked up the atom and string processing predicates in SWI Prolog? The `-->` operator is for defining a DCG. Is that what you intend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try this code.
`:-set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).`
`any(A,K) --> {member(S,K)}, S, {atom_codes(A, S)}.`
`num(S) --> any(S, ["one","two","three","four","five"]).`
`nums([])     --> "".`
`nums([X|Xs]) --> num(X), nums(Xs).`

`split(Str,Ls):-phrase(nums(Ls),Str).`
Ok Now Let's run the query.
`?- split("onethreetwofive", Ls).`
`Ls = [one, three, two, five] ;`

Answer (score 4):

**Use [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)!**

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

num --> "one" | "two" | "three" | "four" | "five".

nums --> "".
nums --> num, nums.
```

Using SWI-Prolog 7.3.15:

```
?- phrase(nums, Cs).
Cs = [] ;
Cs = [o, n, e] ;
Cs = [o, n, e, o, n, e] ;
Cs = [o, n, e, o, n, e, o, n, e] ;
...

?- phrase(nums, "onethreetwofive").
true ;
false.
```

OK! Next, we step up from `num//0` to `num//1` and from `nums//0` to `nums//1`:

```
num(one)   --> "one".
num(two)   --> "two".
num(three) --> "three".
num(four)  --> "four".
num(five)  --> "five".

nums([])     --> "".
nums([X|Xs]) --> num(X), nums(Xs).
```

Let's run the query the OP suggested!

```
?- phrase(nums(Ls), "onethreetwofive").
Ls = [one, three, two, five] ;
false.
```